# Why are the links in this news ticker unclickable?

Tags: html, css

I've attached my **code** below:

```css
.scroll_news_label {
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: 1em; */
    background-color: #eba60b;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.scroll_news_label_text {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.news_scroll::before {
    content: "• ";
    color: #0087c0;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

.news_scroll:first-child::before {
    display: none;
}

.marquee {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.marquee div {
    animation: marquee 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollnews_wrapper">
    <label class="scroll_news_label"> <span class="scroll_news_label_text"> Latest News </span></label>
    <div class="marquee" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
        <div>
            <a class="news_scroll" href="https://www.themigrantproject.org/europe-migrants-libya/"> Europe should stop rescued migrants from being returned to Libya, says IOM </a>
            <a class="news_scroll" href="https://www.themigrantproject.org/greek-forces-push-migrants/"> Greek forces push migrants back to Turkey violently, HRW says </a>
            <a class="news_scroll" href="https://www.themigrantproject.org/libya-europe-migrants/"> Libyan coast guard intercepts 83 Europe-bound migrants </a>
            <a class="news_scroll" href="https://www.themigrantproject.org/sixty-migrants-died-in-turkey/"> Sixty migrants assumed dead after boat sank in Lake Van </a>
            <a class="news_scroll" href="https://www.themigrantproject.org/turkey-intercepts-545-migrants-in-10-days/"> Turkey intercepts 545 migrants in 10 days </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This site](https://www.themigrantproject.org/) has the news ticker below, the links are clickable on every page except the homepage, why is that?

Everything was fine when I used marquee tag but now I rewrote it in CSS since that tag is deprecated and that happened.

Comment: Your code example is producing several errors and more importantly, it doesn't appear to exhibit the issue you describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links are unclickable on that homepage because there's a `.dots` element with a higher `z-index` overlying them, preventing clicks from reaching the link elements below.

[image: screenshot of web inspector]

The simplest way to leave that overlying element alone, stylistically speaking, but allow clicks to hit underlying elements, is this:

```css
.dots {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
#latest-news .dots {
   display: none;
}
```